# How to add a new object using binding source?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I have the following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string HouseNo {get; set;}
}
```

I have a form with a bindingsource which is bound to the `Customer` object. On this form, I have an address usercontrol with its own bindingsource. This usercontrol exposes an `Address` property which is bound to `Customer.Address`.

The databinding works fine because when I load existing records, data is shown correctly.

The problem is that when I create a new `Customer` object, the `Address` is null, and even after the user enters data in the address fields, adresses's bindingsource is DbNull.

If I add the following constructor to the `Customer` class:

```
public Customer()
{
    this.Address = new Address();
}
```

The changes in the address user control and reflected in the binding source and therefore also in the `Customer.Address`.

However, using the above constructor to create an empty `Address` object for the `Customer`, and if the user doesn't enter a valid address (entering an address is optional) and save the customer, EF will cause problems because it tries to save an empty address object with null values.

So what is the correct way to set the child binding source when adding a new parent?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, it sounds like everything is working except for the case where the user *doesn't* enter any address information after creating a new customer when they try to save because the address object contains null values.

I would suggest that you simply validate upon save so that it doesn't allow the user to take the save action if there is missing or improper address information.

Comment: The user is allowed to leave the address fields empty.

Comment: So then I don't understand.  If they're allowed to leave the address fields empty, then what is the problem?

Comment: If Customer.Address is null and address fields are empty, it works fine. If Customer.Address is null and user enter address, bindingSource.DataSource is null and address is not saved.

Comment: Did you use stored procedure or simple insert? In case you use stored procedure check out parameters of it. It's maybe Base side

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono -- I still don't understand then, and that seems to go against what you've said in your question, e.g. "EF will cause problems because it tries to save an empty address object with null values.".  I've retracted my up vote because I no longer believe your question is clear.  Please work on clarifying it.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono -- Also, if the interaction with EF is substantive to the question, please consider tagging it as such.